# NodeJS: Mongoose return wrong results from MongoDB although Mongo shell return correct ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using Express to build my first NodeJS app with the MongoDB as the database and Mongoose as it's modeling tool. I'm following a [tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data) as my guidance.
The problem is when I query MongoDB from my app it returns wrong results, but when I query it from Mongo shell I get correct results.
An example scenario is with the code below which return zero (0) on every count done on my collections though there are documents in there ( which are correctly returned by the Mongo shell):

```
var async = require('async');

var GeneralUser = require('../models/guser');
var Truck = require('../models/truck');
var Trip = require('../models/trip');
var TruckLocation = require('../models/location');

exports.index = function(req, res, next) {
    async.parallel({
        user_count: function(callback) {
            GeneralUser.count(callback);
        },
        truck_count: function(callback) {
            Truck.count(callback);
        },
        trip_count: function(callback) {
            Trip.count(callback);
        },
        location_count: function(callback) {
            TruckLocation.count(callback);
        },

    }, function(err, results) {
        res.render('index', { title: 'My App Home Page', error: err, data: results });
    });
};
```

What is that which I may be missing? Any hint to where I may be doing the wrong way will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
guser.js

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var GUserSchema = Schema(
  {
    firstName: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, minlength: 6, maxlength: 20},
    password: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 8, maxlength: 20},
    gender: {type: String, required: true, enum: ['Male','Female'], default: 'Male'},
    bio: {type: String, match: /[aA-zZ]/, default: ''},
    companyName: {type: String, maxlength: 100, default: ''},
    physicalAddress: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    country: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    mobileNo: {type: String, required: true, match: /[0-9]{12}/, default: '255656516903'},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, match: /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/},
  }
);
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('GeneralUser', GUserSchema);
```

location.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LocationSchema = Schema(
  {
    locationName: String,
    geo: {type: [Number], index: '2dSphere'},
    tripID: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Trip', required: true},
    loggedDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  }
);
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('TruckLocation', LocationSchema);
```

trip.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TripSchema = Schema(
  {
    startingLocation: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    destination: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    routeName: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    plannedDeparture: {type: Date, required: true},
    expectedArrival: {type: Date, required: true},
    containerIsFull: {type: Boolean, required: true},
    truckID: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Truck', required: true},
  }
);
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Trip', TripSchema);
```

truck.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TruckSchema = Schema(
  {
    truckName: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    truckType: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    truckModel: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 100},
    containerNo: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 10},
    truckPass: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 8, maxlength: 20},
    ownerID: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'GeneralUser', required: true},
  }
);
//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Truck', TruckSchema);
```

Above is my models as requested by @Haroon Khan.

It still seem my troubleshooting is leading me nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Truck.count({}, callback);
```